# How access “provided / injected” values from a mixin in VueJS?

Tags: dependency-injection, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I'm trying to access [provided / injected](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) values from a mixin in VueJS. I can see those values from any component but not from the mixin. Is what I'm attempting possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/frang/c6c7kqhp/2/1

```
let myMixin = {
  inject: ['myDependency'],
  created: function() {
    console.log('in mixin', this.myDependency)
  }
}

Vue.component('my-component', {
  inject: ['myDependency'],
  created: function() {
    console.log('in component', this.myDependency)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  provide() {
    return {
        myDependency: 'here is my value'
    }
  },
  mixins: [myMixin]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to inject the `myDependency` property in the same Vue instance that you are providing it.

Vue instances that specify a `provide` property give their child components access to that value via `inject`. But, you cannot `inject` the provided value on the same instance.

You need to use the mixin in a child component:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  mixin: ['myMixin'],
  created: function() {
    console.log('in component', this.myDependency)
  }
})
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/c6c7kqhp/6/)

Comment: Ok, Is there any way to make the mixin global?

Comment: Make the mixin global? Do you mean some way to specify that each component used in the main vue instance uses the same mixin?

Comment: [real use case](https://jsfiddle.net/frang/c6c7kqhp/9/) your answer give a hint for try another way... :+1:

Comment: The only issue is that the mixin do not have the injected values when created it self, but when the component is created

Comment: That's because the vue instance that provides a value cannot access that same value via `inject`. Only the child components can. That's not a problem with the mixin, that's just how the scope of provided values works.

Comment: By the way, do you have any different approach for bootstrap instances in app?

Comment: Not really, but I haven't ever found myself needing to specify a mixin for all components in a project. It seems like you maybe are trying to set up a system for global state maintenance, which [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) is a better tool for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146570/discussion-between-user2976753-and-thanksd).